# Excel VBA Clearing deleted Chart name from memory without closing

Tags: excel, vba, charts, names

So, I have a code that uses the created chart (Charts 1 through 3)
and I also have a code to clear everything so I can run the analyzis again.

The thing is, if I clear everything and try to run, the next 3 charts created will be named from 4 through 6, unless I save close and re-open excel.

Is there a way that, after deleting the charts, the next one created in that worksheet will be named from 1 through 3 again?

Code here:

```
Private Sub Run_Click()

   Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(19, 5), Cells(19 + Cells(16, 4).Value, 5)), _
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(19, 2), Cells(19 + Cells(16, 4).Value, 2)), False, True, 95, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Resultados1").Range("$A$9"),  _
        True, True, True, True, , True
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft -228.75
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop 268.5
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: In my opinion the best think you have to do is to create the chart and then rename it with something relevant to the chart content instead of keep the auto generated name!this will provide easier reference to the chart and you ll be more consistent.
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Name = "NewChart"
        Selection.Name = "NewChart"

Comment: Private Sub R_Click()

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(19, 5), Cells(19 + Cells(16, 4).Value, 5)), _

        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(19, 2), Cells(19 + Cells(16, 4).Value, 2)), False, True, 95, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Resultados1").Range("$A$9" _

        ), True, True, True, True, , True

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft -228.75

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop 268.5

Just the first lines. Charts are named 1 through 3. Id like them available to re-run after deleting

Comment: Can you add a "Specify Chart Name" option to your `Regress` code?  Or call it as a normal Function instead of `Application.Run`, and Return the `Chart` to use in a `With` constructor?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will create two charts called *My_Chart*.

It adds a [ChartObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartobject) which is the container for a chart embedded into a worksheet, before adding the actual [Chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart%28object%29) object to the container.

The `ChartObject` is named and deleted before being recreated again in a different place.
I've added `Debug.Assert False` so the code pauses before deleting the first chart.

```
Sub BuildTwoCharts()

    Dim oCht As ChartObject
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Create 1st chart.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set oCht = wrkSht.ChartObjects.Add _
        (Left:=50, Top:=80, Width:=200, Height:=100)

    With oCht
        .Name = "My_Chart" 'Name it here.
        With .Chart
            .SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1:D4")
        End With

        'Pause code, then delete the chart when you tell it to carry on.
        Debug.Assert False 'Press F5 to continue.
        .Delete
    End With


    'Create 2nd chart.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    With wrkSht
        Set oCht = .ChartObjects.Add _
            (Left:=.Range("H2").Left, Top:=.Range("H2").Top, _
             Width:=.Range("H2:L2").Width, Height:=.Range("H2:H10").Height)
    End With

    With oCht
        .Name = "My_Chart" 'Name it here.
        With .Chart
            .SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1:D4")
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how Excel names its shapes. It keeps a running counter, and uses the next index value for the next shape. The counter resets when you work on another sheet. (There's also a sheet counter and a workbook counter.)

But the first chart you add after deleting all other charts is still ChartObjects(1), whether it's "Chart 1", "Chart 4", or "Chart 54321". So adjust your code:

```
Private Sub Run_Click()

    Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(19, 5), Cells(19 + Cells(16, 4).Value, 5)), _
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(19, 2), Cells(19 + Cells(16, 4).Value, 2)), False, True, 95, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Resultados1").Range("$A$9"),  _
        True, True, True, True, , True
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).IncrementLeft -228.75
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).IncrementTop 268.5
End Sub
```

Comment: That regression will actually create 3 charts. I tried adjusting like that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, guys.

This solution i came up with worked for me:

```
Private Sub RegN_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(19, 5), Cells(19 + Cells(16, 4).Value, 5)), _
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(19, 2), Cells(19 + Cells(16, 4).Value, 2)), False, True, 95, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Resultados1").Range("$A$9" _
    ), True, True, True, True, , True

    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Name = "Chart " & i
    Next i

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft -228.75
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop 268.5
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 3").IncrementLeft -445.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 3").IncrementTop 363
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 2").IncrementLeft -1096.5909448819
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 2").IncrementTop 550
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
```

Since i have a delete everything button installed for using before re-running the analyzis, with this i now don't have to close and re-open the program.

Greets.